# How to add a set of data within an array to the database table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to add a set of data within an array to the database table in Laravel?

This is a result   return $details_list;

[
{
"product_id": "90",
"unit": "1",
"quantity": "10",
"Purchasing_price": "13000",
"row_total": "130000"
},
{
"product_id": "89",
"unit": "1",
"quantity": "10",
"Purchasing_price": "8800",
"row_total": "88000"
},
{
"product_id": "40",
"unit": "1",
"quantity": "3",
"Purchasing_price": "13500",
"row_total": "40500"
}
]

Tried both ways and it didn't work

```
        $Invoices -> details_invoice -> syncWithoutDetaching($details_list);
        $Invoices -> details_invoice -> attach($details_list);
```

This error appears

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::syncWithoutDetaching does not exist.
or
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attach does not exist.

Comment: read the error: `collection` is like the "array wrapper" of laravel. So the `details_invoice` is apparently a relation with multiple models (in a collection).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, and in this case, if you want to save your record as an array, in `Invoices` model you can add below lines :

```
protected $casts = [
    'details_invoice'   =>  'array'
];
```

or, in your controller :

```
$Invoices -> details_invoice = serialize($detail_list);
and when you retrieve this item from database, you should unserialize it.
```

Of course, you need to make sure you've validated everything related to the data, you want to serialize(if the values are from user `inputs/request`).